# Is a whole number float divided by itself guaranteed to be 1.f?

Tags: c++, floating-point

If I write:

```
int x = /* any non-zero integer value */;
float y = x;
float z = y / y;
```

Is `z` guaranteed to be exactly 1.f ?

Comment: It would require a rather unusual amount of pedantry, even by C++ standards, to argue that `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` might be larger than `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`.

Comment: @MSalters Haha, I thought about including that, but decided it's too stupid. :)

Comment: @MSalters: FWIW, for most `x`, `static_cast<int>(y) != x` (if both are 32-bit), but `z` will still be equal to `1.0f` unless `x == 0` because both nominator and denominator have the same rounding error.

Comment: If two numbers `x` and `y` are large enough, and close enough to each other (without being equal), then `x/y` will probably be `1.f` too, due to error in conversion. Try typing this in your browser's console (which probably also uses IEEE754) and hitting ENTER: `9223372036854775700/9223372036854775800`.

Comment: @ArneVogel: Actually, +INF/+INF is NaN, not 1.0

Comment: @MSalters Dunno, that seems like an entirely valid point; it's one of the half-a-dozen-or-so cases in which the above code doesn't return `1f`.

Comment: I wonder if a C++ compiler might actually optimize that out and replace the division by a constant 1.0f ?

Comment: @StephenG It might if it's using a "fast math" optimization approach, but otherwise it'd be considered a compiler bug unless it can prove that the exception cases aren't going to occur in that particular context.  In that exact code above, where the programmer specifies the value of `x` as a literal, it's highly likely that any halfway decent compiler attempting to optimize it would reduce it down to the result.

Comment: @MSalters: Now you just have to show how `y` can be infinite, if both types are 32-bit. D'uh. I was commenting on the IEEE 754 case.

Comment: I'm assuming you only meant to ask about the case of `x != 0`... perhaps you should edit the question accordingly (despite the valid answer about that case).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If your C++ implementation uses IEEE754 then yes, this is guaranteed. (The division operator is required to return the best possible floating point value).

The *only* exceptions for `y / y`, in general, not being `1.f` are the cases when `y` is `NaN`, `+Inf`, `-Inf`, `0.f`, and `-0.f`, or if you are on a platform where  `int` is so wide that certain instances of it cannot be represented in a `float` without that `float` being set to `+Inf` or `-Inf`<sup>1</sup>. Setting aside that final point, in your case that means that `int x = 0;` will produce the only exception.

IEEE754 is extremely common. But to check for sure, test the value of

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>A platform, for example, with a 128 bit `int` and an IEEE754 32 bit `float` would exhibit this behaviour for certain values of `x`.

Comment: I don't think `y` can become NaN.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: You're correct. I've spruced up my sentence.

Comment: If you want to go this route, you'll also need to add Inf, -Inf and -0f. :)

Comment: My, you're correct on those too. Up to this point I've always thought that +Inf / +Inf gave you 1. Thanks for the wandbox sandbox in your answer.

Comment: And possibly the signed NaN ;-)

Comment: NaN does not have a sign, or so I've been told. (Not 100% on that myself.) Also: *"Up to this point I've always thought that +Inf / +Inf gave you 1."* Fortunately not, that would be terrible from a math point of view.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: There are many IEE754 bit patterns which are all `NaN`, some of which have the sign bit set. But as `NaN != NaN`, for any bitpattern of NaN, it's pointless to argue whether "+NaN  == -NaN".

Comment: Some compiler options can tweak floating point operations for the sake of speed. Is it possible some compiler switch could change the answer to this question?

Comment: @BurnsBA That's covered by the "If your C++ implementation uses IEEE754", but yes, that's possible and I agree it's worth spelling out. It can happen if the integer is not exactly representable in `float`, so `y` should be rounded, but it only happens for one of the two operands in `y / y`.

Comment: "In addition GCC offers the -ffast-math flag which is a shortcut for several options, presenting the least conforming but fastest math mode. It enables -fno-trapping-math, -funsafe-math-optimizations, -ffinite-math-only, -fno-errno-math, -fno-signaling-nans, -fno-rounding-math, -fcx-limited-range and -fno-signed-zeros. **Each of these flags violates IEEE in a different way**" which is why I asked, as I'm assuming that would still be "using" IEEE754. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: "To check for IEEE754, check the is_iec559 flag" Haha - gotta love C++!

Comment: Say that `y`'s value was both in a register and in memory, and the compiler chose to load the denominator from memory.  So you wind up with `y_from_register / y_from_memory`. If the register has higher precision than memory does, what's the guarantee that 1 is the best division result?

Comment: Does the Standard guarantee that int-to-float conversions will always be rounded consistently?  Would an implementation that didn't claim IEEE-754 support be non-conforming if e.g. `int x=16777217; float f = (float)x/ (float)16777217;`  yielded 1.00000012f [rounding x up to 16777218.0f and 16777217 down to 16777216.0f]?

Comment: Another exception is when `float` can't contain `x`'s value.

Comment: @Bathsheba when you write "in general" do you mean whole numbers? Or any float (besides 0s,infs,nans)?

Answer (score 33):

No, not in all cases, even for IEEE754.

For example, with `int x = 0;`, you'll get NaN. ([Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O8j5aSzbTLyFOBYA))

Comment: Just slipped that one into my answer before you posted this. Have an upvote.

Comment: I found your wording ambiguous and misleading so I've suggested an edit to make it more clear.

Comment: @cat I can understand the "not in all cases" part of your suggestion, but your use of "For example" suggests that there are other values for which the same applies, and because of that, personally, I think the answer that's here now is better than the answer you suggested.

Comment: @hvd when y is `inf` or `0f` or sign variants of those then the result is also not `1f`

Comment: @cat The question is specifically about *a whole number* float divided by itself and has `float y = x;` with `int x;`.