Why g++ does not optimize this code removing the division (s / s)?
code example compiled with -O3 and -fno-inline in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4rvxccsns
template <class T>
T numbbo(T r, unsigned s) {
    return 10.0 / (static_cast<float>(s) / static_cast<float>(s)) * (-1.0 + r);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return numbbo(static_cast<float>(argc), argc) +
           numbbo(static_cast<double>(argc), argc);
}


Because dividing has side  effects.

ffast-math will really optimize it ;) https://godbolt.org/z/MnoGWj1nx

Removed my previous comments. It's not about INF or NAN because s was originally an unsigned integer and those can always be converted to a finite floating point value. But the value may be 0, resulting in 0/0 == NAN

@Homer512 so it's all because of one extreme edge case that can't be optimized away?  Just wow.

@MarkRansom zero isn't a particular rare number and the compiler cannot randomly break valid code on valid inputs just to save a couple of cycles. In fairness, if you write s = max(s, 1) or similar, the compiler also doesn't optimize it. I assume it isn't smart enough to carry over that information or it just never optimizes float / float because it will also fail for INF and NAN inputs, so it isn't looking back to see if the value range even allows those inputs.

It could make the optimization if one adds if(s == 0) return {}; first I guess ... but it doesn't do that either.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846512/is-a-whole-number-float-divided-by-itself-guaranteed-to-be-1-f

@3CxEZiVlQ -- what observable side effects does dividing have? (note the "observable" -- setting hardware flags doesn't count)

Under IEEE-754, which defines the floating-point rules used by pretty much every compiler these days, 0.0/0,0 is NaN, and 10.0 / NaN is still NaN, not 10.0.

@PeteBecker re setting of flags, I think that's definitely a matter of QOI.  I'd rather FP error flags didn't get randomly set or not set unless I really mean it, personally (and I've seen a situation where aggressive optimization led to spurious division-by-zero flags).

Apart from the fact of an edge case dividing zero by zero, questions about compiler optimisation are quality of implementation concerns.   They are not mandatory.   The explanations for such an optimisation not being performed can range from "compiler developers didn't think of doing it" to things like "not enough demand to justify the cost or development time to implement the optimisation".

The code is taken from https://github.com/numbbo/coco/blob/master/code-experiments/src/f_katsuura.c
I think the right answer is the problem with NaN...
